# How to use Docker and PyCharm on Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, pycharm

I have installed [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/)(not toolbox). It works, but now I want to use PyCharm with Docker and I don't understand from where I need get this data?

Should I first create machine?

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

but if I want to use Docker without any Docker machines, what are the default API URL and certificates folder?

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Jickson no, i also asked at https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/5aox3v/how_to_use_docker_for_mac_and_pycharm/ and don't get answer too, so i don't use pycharm's docker tool, just work in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update PyCharm and therefore Docker integration plugin.

> Plugin v2.5.0 (compatible with IDEA 17.1 EAPs) should [support direct connection](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159223#comment=27-1824701) to `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.

This should be your API URL.

> unix:///var/run/docker.sock

For Certificates folder, it should be set by default to

> ~/.docker/machine/machines/default

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have provided, PyCharm supports only the legacy version of Docker for Mac. The new one needs nor VirtualBox neither Docker Machine.

You could deploy it manually or install the old version of Docker which I wouldn't really recommend.